# What do these Visual Studio directories keep reappearing even when I delete them?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

- Visual Studio2010
- Visual Studio2010Projects
- Visual Studio2010Templates

These started appearing a few months ago, and I didn't really take notice as they're kind of useless. Is there a tool or part of VS2010 that automatically places these directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 (itself) forces these directories to exist as they're the default locations where projects, snippets, templates, and other things are stored. AFAIK, there's no way to change this behavior.

Comment: hmmm. That is not helping my dislike of Visual Studio.  This nonsense doesn't appear on others machines however, so I'm fairly confident it is some oddball addin.  :(

Comment: Well, what add-ins do you have installed?

Comment: I ended up just blowing away my machine. Now they don't appear anymore. Wasn't able to track down what plug in or add on was sticking those in the directories.